# PHP Explaining transmitting POST Data to the Server

Tags: php, http, post

When you POST data to the server in PHP, does it get transmitted through the headers? How does POSTing work?

Comment: If you want to know something exactly, have a look at the RFC :) http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Comment: @Felix, for a beginner , reading the RFC is like taking a razor blade to the eyes...

Comment: @Byron Whitlock: Let's just say it could be difficult to understand. Otherwise it sounds like it is bad, which I believe it isn't ;) At least, it does not hurt to have a look at it and get used to this type of document. And I'm *not* saying one should *only* look at the RFC.

Comment: Also note, that this is not at all related to PHP. HTTP is a language independent protocol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example http POST:

```
POST /login.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mysite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
Content-Length: 27
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

userid=joe&password=guessme
```

As you see, it's not transmitted through the headers, it's the actual content of the POST.

Comment: This is the best answer, however I believe it's referred to as the body of the POST, not the content (official terms).

Answer (score 1):

When you post the data is sent in the body of the request.

You should install [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), and post a form. Look at the net tab to see what is sent.

Answer (score 1):

IN HTTP, a request consists of twp parts, the header and the body. These are seperateed by two newline characters. When you POST somthing, you are sending data in the body part of the request, after the headers. Usually, when POSTing a web form, it is sending the form data in the data section of the request, formatted like a URL query string. Example:
foo=bar&baz=bat

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Great [article](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php)</strike> Better [article](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post/) explaining POST/GET

`POST` includes name/value pairs in the body of the request, while `GET` does so in the query string.

The way that PHP does this is to store all the "posted" values into an associative array called `$_POST`.

```
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$item = $_POST['item'];
```

Also you can view the [Request methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) section of the Hype Transfer Protocol on Wiki, it has the definitions and information on all of the different methods.

Comment: While what you write is correct, it does not at all answer the question.

Comment: I wouldn't say "it does not at all", however I've updated the answer to include more information.

Comment: @Felix : The question was 'Does POST send the data in the headers', the answer here says that it sends it in the body. That sounds like answering the question to me.

Comment: @david: Yes, after the edit it does. Have a loot at the edit history.